# Locate coordinates text in pdf file when using itextpdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using pdfSweep to delete text. However, I have a problem specifying text coordinates. How to determine the exact coordinates of a document in a pdf file?
Link itext: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/removing-content-with-pdfsweep

Answer (score 1):

Your shared link and shared example work just fine.

```
PdfCleanUpLocation location = new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(97, 405, 383, 40),
                ColorConstants.GRAY);
```

In the above example code-> Argument 1 - page number, Argument 2- Region where co-ordinates are specifed, Argument 3- Color with the region should be filled

See the java doc for more https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.11/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/pdfcleanup/PdfCleanUpLocation.html#PdfCleanUpLocation-int-com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle-

If you still face issue, share your code and pdf